# How does Numpy/Scipy turn C functions into vectorized Python functions?

Tags: python, c, numpy, scipy, vectorization

As I understand it, vectorized numpy functions are faster than Python loops because loops are done in C or Fortran. I would like to know where in the source code this happens.

For example, the `scipy.special.bdtr` binomial CDF function accepts array-like arguments `k,n,p` and will return an ndarray provided the arguments are broadcastable. The documentation says that `scipy.special.bdtr` is a wrapper for a routine in the Cephes Mathematical Functions Library. Digging through the source code on Github, I found a `scipy/special/cephes/bdtr.c` file containing the C code for the routine; here are what I believe to be the first three lines of the relevant C function:

> double bdtr(k, n, p)
>
> int k, n;
>
> double p;

It appears that the underlying C function does not operate on arrays, and I can't find the source code where this function is converted to a Python function that operates on arrays.

Comment: "Wrapper" doesn't always mean "direct functional mapping"; the wrapper code itself might do extra things like the looping you mentioned (although the `scipy` front-end is unlikely to be vectorized since CMFL's `bdtr` only works on *one* set of parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of `scipy.special` functions, the C code only contains the "kernels" of the functions, that is, how to apply the function to scalars. Each of these is then wrapped into a [`ufunc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) with automatically generated [Cython](https://cython.org/) code. To do this, it uses C header files, like [`scipy/special/cephes.h`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/cephes.h), Cython declaration files, like [`scipy/special/_cephes.pxd`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/_cephes.pxd), the file [`scipy/special/functions.json`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/functions.json), where all the functions to be generated for `scipy.special` are listed, and finally [`scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py), which is where the Cython code is actually produced.

Comment: It's real hard to read `scipy/special/_generate_pyx.py`, so I looked up how to write custom ufuncs in the Numpy documentation. All that C is Greek to me.

Comment: @BatWannaBe Yes, code generation is hard to read in most cases, and this one is no exception... It seems quite hard to make sense of for a person unfamiliar with it.